# How to change logo from server mail Zimbra

Tags: centos, email-server, zimbra

## Zimbra version

- Release 8.7.0_GA_1659.RHEL6_64_20160628192545 RHEL6_64 FOSS edition.

I have a mail server Zimbra and i need to change the logo of login page.
I have edited in directory

```
/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/skins/_base/logos
```

The following files :

```
AppBanner_black.png
AppBanner.png
AppBanner_white.png
LoginBanner_black.png
LoginBanner.png
LoginBanner_white.png
NotificationBanner.gif
NotificationBanner_grey.gif
TouchLoginBanner@2x.png
TouchLoginBanner.png
TouchWatermarkBanner@2x.png
TouchWatermarkBanner.png
```

The problem is when i access the mail by DNS the logos dont appear, but when i access the mail by IP the logos appear.

PS.: All the pictures have a access level for zimbra user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to be compliant to the license when using de Open Source version.

A snippet from https://blog.zimbra.com/2015/09/change-login-app-logo-open-source-network-edition/ suggests to place 2 banners in the **/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/logos/** folder and change the configuration with:

```
zmprov md example.com zimbraSkinLogoURL https://mail.example.com
zmprov md example.com zimbraSkinLogoLoginBanner /logos/MyLoginBanner.png
zmprov md example.com zimbraSkinLogoAppBanner /logos/MyAppBanner.png
zmmailboxdctl restart
```